# django register_simple_tag send two parameter and how can ı use this in if condition?

Tags: python, django

In my project I want user make just one comment to Doctor profile.So ı choosed to use register_simple_tag and find if user made comment before bu if condition doesn't work.Can anyone know which part is wrong or has the another better way to solve this issue?

commentExist.py

```
register=template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def isCommentExist(request,doctor):
    commmentExist=CommentModel.objects.filter(parent=None,is_published=True,doctor=doctor,comment_user=request.user).count()
    if commmentExist:
        return True
    else :
        return False
```

profile.html

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            {% load commentExist %}
            {% isCommentExist request doctor as existComment %}
                
{% endif %}


{% if existComment  %}
    # make some operation
{% else %}
    # make some operation
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is `commentExist.py` inside a `templatetags` directory? Maybe you could put debug prints and see if it goes through `isCommentExist`. It might be returning `False`

Comment: Yes.The commentExist.py is located in templatetags folder.As you say,it is not working.How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

in profile.html, ı changed location this part to in block content tags.So now it is working.Thanks.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                {% load commentExist %}
                {% isCommentExist request doctor as existComment %}
                    
    {% endif %}
```